# Find the exact value for $\cos(\alpha+\beta)$ given the following information.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Suppose $\alpha$ is interval $$\pi/2 \leq \alpha \leq \pi$$  and $$ \cos(\alpha) = - 1/3 $$ and $\beta$ is in the interval $$0 \leq  \beta \leq \pi/2$$ and $$ \sin\beta = 2/5. $$ Use the facts above to find the exact value of

$$\cos(\alpha + \beta) $$

I think that I should be able to use the identity to solve this but the information that it gave has confused me. How would I solve it and what's the right answer?

Comment: "the identity": which identity? However, the restrictions on $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are needed for you to be able to determine the sign of $\cos \beta$ and $\sin\alpha$, since as you very well know, $\sin x$ determines $\cos x$ up to a sign and viceversa.

Comment: So decide from a triangle? But what abt the pi/2 thing?

Comment: You could use $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$...First , find $\sin(\alpha)$, then $\cos(\beta)$

Comment: @MATHASKER "pi/2 thing" = "restrictions on $\alpha$ and $\beta$"

Comment: Yes, a pair of triangles. The inequalities tell you what quadrant terminal sides are in: an angle $\theta$ is in the first quadrant if $0 < \theta < \pi/2$, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

HINT, we have that:

$$\cos\left(\alpha\right)=-\frac{1}{3}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\alpha=2\pi\text{n}\pm\arccos\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)\tag1$$

Where $\text{n}\in\mathbb{Z}$

Now, we also know that:

$$\frac{\pi}{2}\space<\space\alpha\space<\space\pi\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\frac{\pi}{2}\space<\space2\pi\text{n}\pm\arccos\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)\space<\space\pi\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\text{n}=0\tag2$$

Another way:

$$\cos\left(\alpha+\beta\right)=\cos\left(\alpha\right)\cos\left(\beta\right)-\sin\left(\alpha\right)\sin\left(\beta\right)=-\frac{1}{3}\cdot\cos\left(\beta\right)-\sin\left(\alpha\right)\cdot\frac{2}{5}\tag3$$

Now, you can use:

$$\cos^2\left(\alpha\right)+\sin^2\left(\alpha\right)=\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)^2+\sin^2\left(\alpha\right)=1\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\sin^2\left(\alpha\right)=\frac{8}{9}\tag4$$

And:

$$\cos^2\left(\beta\right)+\sin^2\left(\beta\right)=\cos^2\left(\beta\right)+\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^2=1\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\cos^2\left(\beta\right)=\frac{21}{25}\tag5$$

Comment: Arccos is inverse of cos right? Why is 2pin added/subtracted from arccos(-1/3)

Comment: @MATHASKER Yes, that is true. Because the cosine function is periodic

Comment: I don't understand can u explain it a bit clearly

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Form $2$ triangle with angle $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and put the values in this $$\cos{(A+B)}=\cos A\cos B-\sin A\sin B$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $\alpha \in Q2$, then $\sin (\alpha) = \frac{2 \sqrt{2}}{3}$ and since $\beta \in Q1$, then $\cos (\beta)= \frac{\sqrt{21}}{5}$.

Hence,

\begin{eqnarray}
\cos (\alpha + \beta) &=& \cos (\alpha) \cos (\beta) - \sin (\alpha) \sin (\beta) \\
&=& \left( - \frac{1}{3} \right) \left( \frac{\sqrt{21}}{5} \right) - \left( \frac{2 \sqrt{2}}{3} \right) \left( \frac{2}{5} \right) \\
&=&- \frac{\sqrt{21} + 4 \sqrt{2}}{15}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: but you used existing answers to find this

Comment: how did u find the sin of alpha and cos of beta?

Comment: It's just sin(alpha) = sqrt(1-cos(alpha)^2) etc.